# XAF. When I add a WinModificationsController for a single DetailView I can't save other DetailsViews

Tags: c#, controller, xaf, xpo

I'm starting a project with XAF and I have done a WinModificationsController for a single DetailsView, but seems that when I add that Controller I can't save DetailViews from other object, so the controller works for the class that is targeting but sunddently I can't save other objects. I don't know if I make myself clear, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand from your question your view controller is firing for all detail views, you can add `TargetObjectType` or `TargetViewId` properties into the view controller constructor to only fire the controller for a specific object type or view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheriting the WinModificationsController you need to instead modify that controller by getting a reference to it via Frame.GetController() inside of a view controller. Here's how I did it in one of my view controllers:

```
...
protected override void OnActivated()
{
    base.OnActivated();

    var modifications = Frame.GetController<ModificationsController>();
    if (modifications != null)
    {
        modifications.ModificationsCheckingMode = ModificationsCheckingMode.Always;
        modifications.ModificationsHandlingMode = ModificationsHandlingMode.AutoCommit;
    }
}
```